# WinForms: temporarily disable an event handler

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I disable an event handler temporarily in WinForms?

Comment: Can you share what you're doing at a higher level?  Because you probably don't want to disable _ALL_ event handlers (the form's default paint and move handlers come to mind).

Comment: I just don't want to catch changes in the state of a control when updating it programmatically. And yes, I don't want to disable _ALL_ event handlers, just "an event handler". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744436/winforms-two-way-textbox-problem

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Probably, the simplest way (which doesn't need unsubscribing or other stuff) is to declare a boolean value and check it at the beginning of the handler:

```
bool dontRunHandler;

void Handler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (dontRunHandler) return;

   // handler body...
}
```

Comment: This is simple, but code will be a mess if you use this often.

Comment: won't this be a race condition?

Comment: @k1ngjulien Not if everything's running on the same thread, as it usually is with winforms.

Comment: WinForms requires all UI activity to be on a single thread, so this idiom is safe in single-threaded applications. It is also safe in multi-threaded applications, as long as you meet two conditions: 1. Only call the function from your UI (main) thread, or with `.Invoke()`. (To see if you should call `Invoke()`, you can check `.InvokeRequired`.) 2. Do not assign to or read from the variable directly from any other threads. Note that any invoked calls will not run until the main thread can run it, so beware deadlocks.

Answer (score 59):

Disable from what perspective? If you want to remove a method that's in your scope from the list of delegates on the handler, you can just do..

```
object.Event -= new EventHandlerType(your_Method);
```

This will remove that method from the list of delegates, and you can reattach it later with

```
object.Event += new EventHandlerType(your_Method);
```

Comment: I think you mean your_Method instead of your_Method(). As of C# 2.0, you also don't need the "new EventHandlerType" part - just object.Event += yourMethod; and object.Event -= yourMethod;

Comment: Yep, I meant for it to be sans parens ;). Was not aware of the implicit delegate construction, though; that's good to know.

Comment: This idea works for me(compared to accepted answer) in the scenario where I needed to disable the Handler temporarily for a combobox EditValueChanged.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the event for the component. Pseudocode:

```
YourComponent.YourComponentEvent -= ExistingMethodForTheEvent;
```

Enabling

```
YourComponent.YourComponentEvent += ExistingMethodForTheEvent;
```

Example for events like CellFormatting in DataGridView:

```
//enabling
DataGridView1.CellFormatting += DataGridView1_CellFormatting;
//disabling
DataGridView1.CellFormatting -= DataGridView1_CellFormatting;

private void DgvBillings_CellFormatting(...) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing it in this way, using a control extension.

```
public static void SetDatasource(
  this ComboBox cb, 
  object dataSource, 
  EventHandler _SelectedIndexChanged_eventHandler = null, 
  EventHandler _SelectedValueChanged_eventHandler = null)
{
//disable events
  if (_SelectedIndexChanged_eventHandler != null) cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= _SelectedIndexChanged_eventHandler;
  if (_SelectedValueChanged_eventHandler != null) cb.SelectedValueChanged -= _SelectedValueChanged_eventHandler;
  if (cb.InvokeRequired)
  {
    cb.BeginInvoke(new _d_SetDatasource_ComboBox(SetDatasource), new object[] { cb, dataSource, _SelectedIndexChanged_eventHandler});
  }
  else
  {
    cb.DataSource = dataSource;
    //events enabled again
    if (_SelectedIndexChanged_eventHandler != null) cb.SelectedIndexChanged += _SelectedIndexChanged_eventHandler;
    if (_SelectedValueChanged_eventHandler != null) cb.SelectedValueChanged += _SelectedValueChanged_eventHandler;
  }
}
private delegate void _d_SetDatasource_ComboBox(ComboBox cb, object dataSource, EventHandler _SelectedIndexChanged_eventHandler = null, EventHandler _SelectedValueChanged_eventHandler = null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the just one event handler for a bunch of checkboxes or radio buttons you can also use something like:

```
var lSender = sender as RadioButton;
if (lSender?.Checked != true)
    return;
```