# Neat solution to temporarily unsubscribe from an event

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, event-handling

I'm looking for a neat solution for temporarily unsubscribing from a WinForm event. For example, if I have a textBox1 control with the following event handler:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  // Do something
}
```

I don't want this event to fire when I programmatically change the contents of the textbox. But instead of writing:

```
  try
  {
    textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;
    // Change textbox contents without triggering event
  }
  finally
  {
    textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
  }
```

I'm looking for something I can use similar to this:

```
using(new EventInhibitor(textBox1.TextChanged, textBox1_TextChanged))
{
  // Change textbox contents without triggering event
}
```

The problem is how I can pass the textBox1.TextChanged event to the constructor? Reflection? Expressions?

```
public class EventInhibitor : IDisposable
{
  private bool _disposed = false;
  private XXX _event;
  private EventHandler _handler;

  public EventInhibitor(XXX event, EventHandler handler)
  {
    _event   = event;
    _handler = handler;
    _event -= _handler;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    if(_disposed)
      return:
    _event += _handler;
    _event = null;
    _handler = null;
    _disposed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a strange problem. What sort of exception do you expect to occur on the line that sets the Text property? If there is a lot on the right-side of the assignment, perhaps that should be handled before setting the Text property and inside a try..catch where you would then not have to re-establish the event handler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744494/winforms-temporarily-disable-an-event-handler

Comment: `textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;` **won't never throw exception**.

Comment: This is a very simplified example. The actual case right now involves adding and removing both rows and columns in a ListView. Around 10-15 code lines that might get an exception thrown some times. I could check everything that might throw before i disable the event, but I think the code will be less clear that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use reflection (so don't forget to import `System.Reflection`). You can pass the control (or object if you want it to be more generic) and the name of the event as a string:

```
public class EventInhibitor : IDisposable
{
  private bool _disposed = false;
  private EventInfo _event;
  private EventHandler _handler;
  private Control _control;

  public EventInhibitor(Control c, string EventName, EventHandler handler)
  {
    _event = c.GetType().GetEvent(EventName); 
    _handler = handler;
    _control = c;
    _event.RemoveEventHandler(_control, _handler);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
      if (_disposed)
          return;

      _event.AddEventHandler(_control, _handler);
    _event = null;
    _handler = null;
    _control = null;
    _disposed = true;
  }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
using (new EventInhibitor(textBox1, "TextChanged", textBox1_TextChanged))
{
    textBox1.Text = "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: I started to go down this route before I posted the question, but I didn't like specifying the event using a string. I got a new idea from your answer though, it might be possible to just pass a Control to the class and have it disable *all* events. But on the other hand, I would need to store all event handlers that are subscribing to each event and I don't think that information is available outside the Control class?

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution.. which just calls functions before and after:

```
public class EventInhibitor : IDisposable {
    private bool _disposed;
    private Action _after;

    public EventInhibitor(Action before, Action after)
    {
        before();
        _after = after;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        _disposed = true;
        _after();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using(new EventInhibitor(() => textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged, 
                         () => textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged)) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution you want, this is how I've always solved this problem in the past.

```
TextBox myTextBox;

private string _text;
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return _text;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_text != value)
        {
            _text = value;

            OnTextChanged();
        }
    }
}

private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Text != myTextBox.Text)
    {
        // the user must have edited the TextBox
        Text = myTextBox.Text;
    }
}

private void OnTextChanged()
{
    if (myTextBox.Text != Text)
        myTextBox.Text = Text;
}
```

This way when the user changes the text by typing in the box it raises event and executes some code of your choice.  But if you set the Text property manually it will only raise the event once and not twice.  If you want to react differently to when the user edits the textbox then you can put some extra code in the event handler and it will only execute when the text changed because of user input.

This way you can disassociate different aspects of how you want to handle the text changing.  For example you might want to execute code in `OnTextChanged()` which updates another control regardless of whether the Text changed due to user actions or your app logic.